# How to undo the committed changes in a third party library which has been added through pod in Git

Tags: git, cocoapods

I am working on a swift project. I have removed and added one brace in a third party library directly by mistake and committed to the remote branch. How can I remove/override this commit? This mistake happened in the second commit out of a total of seven commits.I am so worried because I believe we can not edit directly in a third party library which has been added through a pod even though my change is just the deletion and addition of a brace. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

Comment: The affected commit is not the recent commit but the second out of 7 commits.. updated the question..